# Tor Browser startup hangs forever

Tags: catalina, startup, tor

Tor browser startup hangs forever in the "Establishing Connection" window with the progress bar absolutely empty.
Searching Tor forums has given to help.

Comment: Which specific version of TOR Browser are you using?

Comment: Tor Browser 10.5.2

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure there is no TOR browser process hanging around anymore (run `ps aux | grep -i 'tor.*rowser'` and kill any remaining processes)
- `rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data`
- Download and install most recent version from https://www.torproject.org/download/